# How to sort table by custom defined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using rails 5 with PostgeSQL and I have model with 2 columns:

```
amount: integer
interval_count: integer
```

I have custom method defined in my model `amount_per_interval` that basically returns `amount/interval_count` (it calculates it on app level). Now I need to sort whole table by this `amount_per_interval` value, but I need to do it on database level, because I'm using pagination (and also I have millions of those records so I don't want to load all of them into memory).

Is there any possibility to define such custom ordering on this model? I can't find any solution.

Update:

I basically want to rewrite this SQL:

```
SELECT (amount / interval_count) as amount_per_interval FROM my_table ORDER BY amount_per_interval
```

into ActiveRecord's interface and still keep compatibility with pagination and other AR methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding `amount_per_interval` to your table if you need it for sorting. You can calculate it every time you insert a record.
You can then do this in your SQL query :

```
SELECT (...) ORDER BY amount_per_interval
```

or using Rails query interface :

```
YourModel.order(amount_per_interval: :desc)
```

which generates this query

```
SELECT "table_name".* FROM "table_name" ORDER BY "table_name"."amount_per_interval" DESC
```

This loads all records ordered by `amount_per_interval` from highest to lowest.

Comment: I will consider that but I still have hope it's not necessary. In raw SQL it's pretty easy: `SELECT (amount / interval_count) as amount_per_interval FROM my_table ORDER BY amount_per_interval` but I can't find how to rewrite this into rails and still keep it compatible with other AR methods and pagination.

Comment: You can still do this :

`YourModel.select("amount / interval_count AS amount_per_interval").order("amount_per_interval")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `select` and `order` methods:

```
YourModel.select("*, (amount / interval_count) as amount_per_interval")
         .order("amount_per_interval")
```

To access the `amount_per_interval`, you could just call it on the object that is loaded with the statement above.

```
your_model_object.amount_per_interval
```